# Creating a historical data set in Power Bi from a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Monthly I send out forms that must be completed. The people looking at the Power Bi report that I have created want to see the historical data. They want to know on the 3rd 5th and 10th what percentage of the company has completed the survey on a monthly basis. So for example by the 3rd of February 82% completed but by the 3rd of March 83% had completed it. These forms are for compliance policies. How could I set this up in Power Bi? Another way to do this would be to run some sort of SQL Stored Procedure like this but I don't know the best way to do this to make it dynamic for the year.

```
SELECT 
AnsweredSurvey,
Month,
ModifiedDate
FROM Answers
WHERE Year = YEAR(getDate()) 
AND TemplateId = '439D8B35-4CAC-4D71-946A-BB67E8BAC19F' 
AND ModifiedDate < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getDate()), 02, 04)
```

But this does not account for being able to see previous years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by making several measures in Power BI that are able to be manipulated by a filter.